# Calling variable within variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Can anyone provide me solution for calling variable within another variable in JMeter.

Eg. I have two variables (var1 & var2) and var1 has as 'number' and I would like to have a result by calling both the variables using single reference as mentioned below:

${var1_${var2}}

I would need above reference to work as below:

- First ${var2} should call and provide its value [Output - ${var1_number}]
- Then ${var1_number} provides its value so that I can get the final value

Please let me know if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

~
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to post the full "correct answer" next time, and not just another reference. It could help us, who finding the question here on stackoverflow.

**My case**:

Using `testtype` to select attribute for a URL-call

`url1` = something
`url2` = somethingelse

To get my variable value from url1, i defined `testtype` as `url1`. But `${${testtype}}` didn't do the trick.

The solution is the `__V` function as you mentioned, formatted like this:

`${__V(${testtype})}`

And therefore, i'm ending up with `something` as the value with `${__V(${testtype})}`.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I got the answer myself by using '__V' function of JMeter.